# Flutter how to download files and save it into phone storage

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm writing a flutter app in which I want to download files from an URL when I write this URL in my browser the file download
I want to do the same with flutter and I want to store the file in the phone local storage

I tried with `dio` and `path provider` without any result it show me that the file is downloaded but I do not find it in local storage this is my method

```
Future <void> dow5tn()async{

    var dir=await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    Dio dio=Dio();
    dio.download('http://192.168.43.24:27017/api/posts/uknoww','${dir.path}/filename.pdf');
  }
```

Comment: You can use open_file package to open the downloaded file..

Comment: the file did not exist in phone storage

Comment: What's the response you are getting after download file? From dio?

Comment: what you mean the response is only the file

Comment: Response response = await dio. download () ; and check response. staruscode=?

Comment: ok the response statuscode is 201